# Symfony Query doctrine entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with a query in doctrine i started using Symfony recently for to be continued a old project in Symfony and now i want learn it.
I start to explain from db and i write only the fields that interest me :

- user(id,name,surname,phat)
- user_reference(id,id_user[FOREIGN KEY id FROM user],id_user_referenced[FOREIGN KEY id FROM user])

This is the query :

```
     $id_user = $user->getId();
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('ur','uu')   
     ->from('DtEcBundle:UserReferences', 'ur')
     ->innerJoin("ur.id_user","uu")
     ->where("ur.id_user = :id_user")
     ->setParameter("id_user",$id_user)
            ->getQuery();
            $userpyramid = $query->getResult();
```

I print in my twig file id_user_referenced but i would print too "name, surname and path" from USER table

For print id_user_referenced in the Entity UserReferences there is this code:

```
    /**
 * Set id_user_referenced
 *
 * @param \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $idUserReferenced
 * @return UserReferences
 */
public function setIdUserReferenced(\Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $idUserReferenced = null) {
    $this->id_user_referenced = $idUserReferenced;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get id_user_referenced
 *
 * @return \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getIdUserReferenced() {
    return $this->id_user_referenced;
}
```

Transform a number like id to string in Entity User with:

```
    public function __toString(){
    return strval($this->id);
}
```

Now if i add to my query in the select this:

```
->select('ur','uu.path')
```

Symfony send me an error:

> Key "idUserReferenced" for array with keys "0, path" does not exist in
>   DtEcBundle:Profilo:digitalpr-profile.html.twig at line 40

Why?? How can i solved it??

**UserReferences.php**

```
 namespace Dt\EcBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
 * UserReferences
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_references" ,uniqueConstraints=         {@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="recension_unique", columns={"id_user",      "id_user_referenced"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Dt\EcBundle\Entity\UserReferencesRepository")
 */  class UserReferences {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 *
 * @var Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User",     inversedBy="references")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
  private $id_user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_referenced", referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
private $id_user_referenced;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="reference", type="text", nullable=false,unique=false);
 */
private $reference;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set reference
 *
 * @param string $reference
 * @return UserReferences
 */
public function setReference($reference) {
    $this->reference = $reference;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get reference
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getReference() {
    return $this->reference;
}

/**
 * Set id_user
 *
 * @param \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $idUser
 * @return UserReferences
 */
public function setIdUser(\Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $idUser = null) {
    $this->id_user = $idUser;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get id_user
 *
 * @return \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getIdUser() {
    return $this->id_user;
}

/**
 * Set id_user_referenced
 *
 * @param \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $idUserReferenced
 * @return UserReferences
 */
public function setIdUserReferenced(\Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $idUserReferenced = null) {
    $this->id_user_referenced = $idUserReferenced;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get id_user_referenced
 *
 * @return \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getIdUserReferenced() {
    return $this->id_user_referenced;
}
}
```

**User.php**

```
    /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=false, nullable=false)  
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.name.not.blank")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *          min=2,
 *          max=150,
 *          minMessage="user.name.not.min",
 *          maxMessage="user.name.not.max" )
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255, unique=false, nullable=false)  
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.surname.not.blank")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *          min=2,
 *          max=150,
 *          minMessage="user.surname.not.min",
 *          maxMessage="user.surname.not.max" )
 */
protected $surname;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(name="borndate", type="datetime",unique=false,nullable=false) 
 */
protected $borndate;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="tel", type="string",length=50, unique=true,nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Regex("/[0-9]/")
 */
protected $tel;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string",length=255,unique=false,nullable=true) 
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.expert.city.not.blank",groups={"Expert"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.expert.city.not.blank",groups={"ExpertProfile"})
 * @Assert\Length(
 *          min=2,
 *          max=150,
 *          minMessage="user.expert.city.not.min",
 *          maxMessage="user.expert.city.not.max", groups={"Expert"} )
 * @Assert\Length(
 *          min=2,
 *          max=150,
 *          minMessage="user.expert.city.not.min",
 *          maxMessage="user.expert.city.not.max", groups={"ExpertProfile"} )
 */
protected $city;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="string",length=255,unique=false,nullable=true) 
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.expert.street.not.blank",groups={"Expert"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.expert.street.not.blank",groups={"ExpertProfile"})
 * @Assert\Length(
 *          min=2,
 *          max=150,
 *          minMessage="user.expert.street.not.min",
 *          maxMessage="user.expert.street.not.max", groups={"Expert"} )
 * @Assert\Length(
 *          min=2,
 *          max=150,
 *          minMessage="user.expert.street.not.min",
 *          maxMessage="user.expert.street.not.max", groups={"ExpertProfile"} )
 */
protected $street;

/**
 *
 * @var type
 * 
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "1024k",
 *     mimeTypes = {"image/gif","image/jpeg","image/pjpeg","image/png"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "user.image.mimetypes",
 *     maxSizeMessage   = "user.image.maxsize"
 * )
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.expert.mandatory.photo",groups={"Expert"})
 * 
 */
protected $photo;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo_path",type="string", length=255, nullable=true,unique=true)
 */
protected $path;
/**
 * Membri per la gestione dei file
 * 
 */
```

Comment: Can you show your twig? I mean **DtEcBundle:Profilo:digitalpr-profile.html.twig at line 40**

Comment: Can you show mappings of these objects DtEcBundle:UserReferences and DtEcBundle:User?

Comment: At least one possible problem I see is this innerJoin("ur.id_user","uu"). It should be probably innerJoin("ur.user","uu") - you have set the name of object's property, not a field in database. But we should see mappings to be sure

Comment: @Dmitry Malyshenko  I update the post with Entity

Comment: @Dmitry Malyshenko there is a part of code again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try in this mode but is not good

```
  $id_user = $user->getId();
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('ur','uu')   
     ->from('DtEcBundle:UserReferences', 'ur')
     ->innerJoin("ur.id_user","uu")
     ->where("ur.id_user = :id_user")
     ->setParameter("id_user",$id_user)
            ->getQuery();
            $userpyramid = $query->getResult();


    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('form', 'form')
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('profilo_secondlevel'))
        ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'Prova'])
        ->getForm();*/


        $result->getIdUserReferenced()->getPath();

    return $this->render('DtEcBundle:Profilo:index.html.twig', array(
        'user'              => $user,
        'tags'              => $tags,
        'followers'         =>$followers,
        'expert'            =>$expert,
        'user_expert'       =>$user_expert,
        'well_cat'          =>$well_cat,
        'user_notification' => $user_notifications,
        "udputenti" => $udputenti,
        "userpyramid" => $userpyramid,
        "result"=> $result
        //'form'=>$form->createView()
    ));`
```

Comment: I think $userpyramid will have an array of UserReference. Make var_dump($userpyramid) and you will see an hierarchy of objects in a result

Comment: Yes, if i print {{dump(userpyramid)}} in my twig file i get this 
`array:3 [▼
  "id" => 4
  "reference" => "prova"
  "id_user" => array:33 [▶]
]`

but there isn't id_user_referenced.. I get id_user_referenced only with IdUserReferenced ...

Comment: So $userpuramid is an array of UserReference. So in twig must work {{userpyramid[0].id_user_referenced.path}}

Comment: or {% for reference in userpyramid %} {{reference.path}} {% endfor %}

Comment: give me and error for variable $result.. @Dmitry Malyshenko

Comment: Please make a var_dump of $query

Comment: @Dmitry Malyshenko i make a dump of userpyramid variable and give me all about user_references but not id_user_referenced

array:3 [▼
  "id" => 4
  "reference" => "prova"
  "id_user" => array:33 [▶]
]

With _{{userpyramid[0].id_user_referenced.path}}_ give me this error:

**Key "0" for array with keys "id, reference, id_user" does not exist in DtEcBundle:Profilo:digitalpr-profile.html.twig at line 44**..

if i write _$results->getIdUserReferenced()->getPath();_ give this error
**Notice: Undefined variable: results**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that doctrine hydrates your result in [Array Hydration](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#array-hydration) mode, while you expect [Object Hydraion](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#object-hydration).

In the first case you ask for 2 related objects and doctrine can link them. In the second you ask for an object and for a scalar value, and doctrine cannot link them, so it returns them in two separate fields of an result array.

So the result that you have got from $query->getResult() in case of `select('ur','uu.path')` is not an array of User objects, but an array of 2 fields - $result[0] where you have all found User objects, and $result['path'] for uu.path - because uu.path is scalar value rather than object.

So you need to make `select('ur','uu')` and address your result as `$result->getIdUserReferenced()->getPath()`.

Or (if you want to save some resources, but I don't think it worth it) make `select('ur','uu.path')` and then make var_dump of result. And you will see how to address to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i don t understand, where i put `$result->getIdUserReferenced()->getPath()` in my controller? After the query??